# Javascript copy to clipboard and paste it into text editor new line

Tags: javascript

I know that this question has been asked before many times, but i couldn't find a way to handle this problem. I have a string that contains "\n" characters to denote new line and i am copying this string to clipboard. For now everything is OK but when i try to paste this clipboard into a text editor (i am using gedit in Ubuntu) the "\n"s are still there and the lines are not separated. What can i do to show these lines separated in text editors also?

```
app.ports.copyToClipboard.subscribe(function(str){
    console.log("got from elm is "+str);
    var dummy = document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute("id","csvValue");
    document.getElementById("csvValue").value = str;
    document.getElementById("csvValue").select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

"str" is the string that i need to copy to clipboard. 
And that's the text shown in text editor :

```
Year;sharpe;dailyz;dailysd;cum;ct/mil;rSP;rCTA;rZ250\n"2014";2.431;2.431;0.00003;10205.49;0;0;0;0\n
```

Comment: nope. that's pure javascript and this function talks to elm.

Comment: Is the \n from a textarea?

Comment: \n comes from an input field as it was written in 3rd line of code.

Comment: I am asking what that input is....

Comment: i'm creating this input field just for selecting the string to use in execCommand('copy'). the desired copy string is str.

Comment: What is the input.... Is it a textbox, is it a textarea?

Comment: now i recognize that i didn't specify the type of input. is the textarea type reasonable for that process?

Comment: where does `str` actually come from? Before you put it in the input?

Comment: So your issue is the person is typing in \n and you are expecting that to be a line feed on the other end??

Comment: str is an automatically created string from table and it comes from an elm application. anyone does not writing anything. the string is created by elm application.

Comment: Holy crap I am not awake, I missed `var dummy = document.createElement('input');`   I swore it was getElementById... lol. If you change that to textarea, see if that makes a difference.